# How to resolve promise from a mocked callback function in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am new to jest and trying to get some understanding of how mocks work. I am not able to figure out how I resolve an actual promise from a mocked module function.
I have a simple data interface module as shown below

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function loadData(fileName){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, `/${fileName}`), (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err)
              reject(err);
            }
            data = data.toString();
            try{
                data = JSON.parse(data);
            }
            catch(err){
                console.error(err)
                reject(new Error('Error while parsing json'))
            }
            resolve(data);
        })
    })
    return promise;
}
```

The test file for the module looks like

```
jest.mock('fs');

const fs = require('fs');
const DI = require('./../data/data_interface');


describe('data loading functionality',() => {
    test('load data opens file system',async () => {
        try {
            expect.assertions(1);
            let fileName = 'expenses.json';
            await DI.loadData(fileName);
           expect(fs.readFile.mock.calls.length).toBe(1); 
        }
        catch(err){
            throw(err);
        }
    })
})
```

When I run the above test I am getting a timeout error which seems because the mock is not able to resolve the promise.
How do I resolve a promise from the provided mock?

Comment: The Jest docs have [an example of mocking `fs`](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules=) that might be helpful. In the docs, they create a manual mock at `__mocks__/fs.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the async await in your test